# What is the infinite open covering of this set $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ under the product topology, such that no finite subset covers $b$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ be the infinite cartesian product of $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the product topology.

Let $b$ be the following set in $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$, where for for finite $n$:

$b = [a_1, b_1] \times ... \times [a_n, b_n] \times X_1 \times X_{2} \times .. \times X_i \times ..$

and where for $i=\{1,2,...\}$, we have $X_i =\mathbb{R}$.

I read that this set is not compact, i.e. there exists an open covering of this set such that no finite subset of which can cover $b$ ....

But then again, I am not sure if it is possible to construct an infinite open covering of this set such that for each element of the covering, none of the $X_i$ is covered by the single set $\mathbb{R}$.

What I mean is, take for instance, if $b$ is covered by the following open sets, where for some $\epsilon > 0$:

$c = (a_1 - \epsilon, b_1 ) \times .. \times (a_n - \epsilon, b_n ) \times .. \mathbb{R} \times ..$

$d = (a_1, b_1 + \epsilon) \times .. \times (a_n, b_n + \epsilon) \times .. \mathbb{R} \times ..$

Then $c$ and $d$ form a finite covering of $b$ since all factors of $c$ and $b$ after the $n$th index is $\mathbb{R}$

So to make an infinite covering such that no finite combination of which covers $b$, I guess we should have the following type of cover $C$:

Let $C$ denote an open infinite covering of $b$, and let $\pi_i$ denote the projection function for the $i$th component of the product. For open set $c \in C$ that forms part of the covering, we have $\pi_i(c) = A_i$, where $A_i \neq \mathbb{R}$ for all $i$.

But there seems to be a contradiction here, since it looks like that $C$ is not valid under the product topology (as this means that for each element $c \in C$ the number of sets that are not equal to $\mathbb{R}$ approaches infinity ...)

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need such covering. $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact. Take $\{ U_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in N}$ an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$ with no finite sub cover. Then define

$$V_\alpha = [a_1,b_1] \times ... \times [a_n,b_n] \times U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R} \times ... \times \mathbb{R} \times ...$$

Then $\{ V_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an open cover with no finite sub cover.

Comment: oh right ! thanks